# How to capture request header in azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm currently running a windows azure web app behind an application gateway v2.
I would like to use header information for x-forwarded-host or x-original-host - but it does not work.
Now I'd like to trace what request headers are actually received by the web app. I'm trying network-capturing. But as the whole traffic is HTTPs - I guess I'm not seeing all the fields.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure application gateway to modify request and response headers and URL by using [`Rewrite HTTP headers and URL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers-url) or to modify the URI path by using a path-override setting. However, unless configured to do so, all incoming requests are proxied to the backend.

For more details, you can read [the offical document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works#modifications-to-the-request).

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of this. But I'd like to monitor what is coming in into my web app service.